# Android relative layout scaling and aligning

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

I need to design an Andorid layout that is given below, however I cannot handle positioning properly.

[image]

Here is the types of view parts and my constraints:

- A: Image View, fixed width, fix height, left-aligned
- B: Text View, auto-scaled width, fix height
- C: Text View, auto-scaled width, fix height
- D: Text View, auto-scaled width, fix height
- E: Text View, auto-scaled width, fix height
- F: Image View, fixed width, fix height, right-aligned

I tried relative layout but I cannot handle the rightmost view (ie. F). So what should be the proper XML markup for this layout?

Comment: Did you tried to align F with alignParentRight?

Comment: Yes, but this time E does not scale properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fairly straightforward. Try something like this (I've left out the other stuff like height and width to save space):

```
    <RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/A"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/F"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/A"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/F"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/B"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/C"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/D"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/E"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/A"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/F"
            android:layout_below="@+id/container" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting some of your code that you tried would help us figure out what you tried so far.  But why isn't relative layout working for you?  Have you tried something like

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageViewF"
android:layout_alightParentRight="true" />
```

Try reading about [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) if you haven't already

Comment: Yes I tried relative layout, but the whole layout is a bit complicated.